# DIRECT Link vs Redirect

Tags: redirect, hyperlink

What is the difference between a DIRECT Link and a Redirect?

I am looking at an API: 
https://remoteok.io/api?ref=producthunt

And they say:

> [{"legal":"By using Remote OK's API feed you legally agree to mention Remote OK as a source and link back to the job listing URL on Remote OK with a DIRECT link, no redirects please.

I am not sure what they mean by I can use a DIRECT Link but not a Redirect. Aren't they the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When linking *externally* (from your site to someone else's website), it's common practice to link to your own site first (so that you know how many users clicked the link) and then redirect to the external site.

Redirect would mean HTTP [301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) and [302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) codes.

A *direct* link to example.com would look like this:

```
<a href="example.com">example.com</a>
```

An *indirect* link to example.com would look like this:

```
<a href="bit.ly/2yHIefP">example.com</a>
```

Comment: ah so, let's say I have a mobile app with a link to their site. The user clicks the link on my app then a webview opens up their site.

That is considered a direct link?

Comment: @grantespo if the domain you put in address bar is the same as the site, this is a direct link. If it does somewhere else but eventually gets to the target site (with no user interaction required), that's a redirect.

Comment: @grantespo no worries, sorry I couldn't find a better example. SO won't let me put the full bit.ly URL, but if you copy paste the second HREF into your browser and open dev tools, you'll see what I mean.